# None check preceding an isinstance check good practice?

Tags: python

Is it good practice to test for not `None` preceding an `isinstance` check in Python? For example:

```
if x is not None and isinstance(x, (int, float)):
    # Some code over here 
    pass
```

Or can I do without and is this sufficient?

```
if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
    # Some code over there 
    pass
```

Comment: if `x` is None, then the `isinstance` would return False anyway, so the `is not None` check is redundant.

Comment: I'd say this depends on your "use cases" (and this question risks being considered opinion-based), but **usually**, the "Pythonic" way is more a *rather ask for forgiveness (handle exceptions) than for permission*. For instance, `x = float(x)` will either make your `x` a float or give you a ValueError (`float("foo")`) or a TypeError (`float(None)`). I'd say you can put that casting to `float` in a try/except block and handle exceptions as needed.

Comment: One case where it would be necessary: if your `isinstance` call included `object` in the sequence of types to check against. (But since `isinstance(x, object)` is, by definition of `object`, true for any `x`, that would be a silly thing to do.)

Comment: @Coldspeed For now I won't accept an answer as it doesn't add anything to what I already know. Obviously I tried the answers given in this thread myself before asking. I just want to know what is best to do as dealing with `None` requires caution in Python (and other languages where it is called `null`).

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? That request seems... broad.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, doing a `is not None` check is unnecessary, because -

```
>>> isinstance(None, (int, float))
False
```

Meaning, if `x` is `None`, then the `isinstance` condition would return `False` anyway, making the `x is not None` check redundant. So, in summary,

```
if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
    ...
```

Works just as well.

---

Furthermore, if you want to test whether an object is numeric in nature, a simpler way to do so would be using the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number) module -

```
import numbers
if isinstance(x, numbers.Number):
    ...
```

Note that `numbers.Number` tests all numeric objects from the very root of the hierarchy. This also includes complex numbers, so if that isn't what you want, you can test with `numbers.Real` to `numbers.Rational` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 20 2017, 01:25:59) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> isinstance(None, (int, float))
False
>>>
```

It raises no error, so I would actually prefer the version without the 'is None' check, as it is just less code.